# Double counting partial and exact string matches

Tags: python, string, while-loop, match

I am writing a program in python which generates a random string of letters and lets a user try and guess the string(out of the possible letters R O Y G B or P). The random string is four characters long, and after the user enters a guess, tells the user how many exact matches, i.e. right letter right position, and how many partial matches, i.e. right letter wrong position. The problem is, my code for computing partial matches seems to double count exact matches. for example, if the code is RGPB, and the user guesses RGYO, it would report 2 exact 2 partial.
any insights on how to best fix this?

```
partialMatches = 0
i = 0
while i < len(guess):
    p = 0
    while p < len(secret):
        if guess[i] == secret[p]:
            partialMatches = partialMatches + 1 
        p += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Easy, subtract exacts from partials. Or check `if guess[i] == secret[p] and i != p`.

Comment: of course, can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternate (and I suppose more Pythonic) solution:

```
exact_matches = sum(1 for (x, y) in zip(guess, secret) if x == y)
partial_matches = len(set(secret) & set(guess)) - exact_matches
```